# Do I need to backup Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have sync activated for Chrome.

Is there still a need to backup the profile folder on my machine?

On windows, that would be the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome`, on Linux that would be `~/.config/google-chrome`.

My question is motivated by the fact that this folder changes a lot and forces my backup tool to include it in the incremental changes.

Answer (score 5):

I have never backed up Chrome before and I am always switching between various Operating Systems. Logging in with my Google account pulls over the all the bookmarks, passwords, and history without ever having to manually transfer/restore the profile.

The %LocalAppData% changes a lot because all of the upgrades are installed here, as it does not require admin rights and allows for the upgrade to occur without any user intervention. The company I work for deploys the same tactic for our app too.

So, long story short, no you do not need to backup the profile. You can 100% rely on Chrome sync :-)